# Convergence of the infinite series $2^x\ln(1+1/3^x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

The Q: determine whether the series converges or not

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k\ln(1+1/3^k) $$

So far I figured out that the function is positive and decreasing on [1,infinity).

I decided to try integral test but solving the improper integral turned out to be very long and difficult (I tried integrate by parts). So instead of doing integral test I tried doing limit comparison test, with $$a_n=2^x\ln(1+1/3^x), b_n=2^x$$ but I ended up with 0. I'm lost as to what to do next, or should I have just continued with the integral test?

Also I graphed it and it should converge to 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Try the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use: $\ln(1 + x) < x$, and the geometric series with $r = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: ca you expand on that? Idk what I can do with what you just gave me.

Comment: Replace ln(1 + 1/3^x) by 1/3^x, and then use (2/3)^x for the new series

Comment: try this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727378/not-sure-which-test-to-use