# Not sure which test to use?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Trying to determine if the following series is convergent:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} {2^k\ln \Big(1+\frac{1}{3^k}\Big)}$$

I have no idea how to compute the integral so im not sure if I should use the integral test, but what other test is there that I could use? Ratio test? Another one maybe??

Comment: $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ near $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $0 < \ln(1+x) < x$ for all $x > 0$.

Hence the sum is between $0$ and 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{3^k} = 2 \;.
$$

Comment: This upper bound is nice since the numerical value of the sum which is considered in the post is $1.87878$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No wonder since keeping one more term in the expansion of $\log$ yields the lower bound $2-\frac17=1.857$.

Answer (score 0):

note $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$ this implies that for small $x$'s we have $$\ln(1+x)\approx x$$ said differently  for large $n$'s we can interchange $$\ln(1+1/3^n)\approx 1/3^n$$ then your series behaves as... $$\sum 2^n \ln(1+1/3^n)\approx \sum  2^n \cdot (1/3^n)  =\sum(2/3)^n$$ which clearly converges... use can use Limit Comparison Test to make it more rigorous if you like..

Answer (score 0):

$ln(x+1)$ is equivalent to $x$ near $x = 0$

so

$ln(1+\frac{1}{3^k})$ equivalent to $\frac{1}{3^k}$ near 0
so : 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{3^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{3})^k$$
which is a geometric seri, and $$r =\frac{2}{3} < 1$$ so it converges !